# Am I able to move my docker repositories or images from Amazon ECR directly to another ECR repository on a different account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

After many hours of research the only solution I could come up with was pulling the images one by one, then logging in to the other account and pushing the images to that one. My internet is really bad and I do not have the storage space to be doing it this way. Is there and easier way?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333302/copy-docker-image-from-one-aws-ecr-repo-to-another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy docker image from one AWS ECR repo to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333302/copy-docker-image-from-one-aws-ecr-repo-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must pull, tag, and push. If your internet is bad, consider spinning up an AWS EC2 spot instance for a few hours to get the migration completed quickly.

I wrote a bash script for this. You can specify the number of tagged images that will be copied.

https://gist.github.com/virtualbeck/a635ef6701991f2087384eab7edbb18b